# config.php in opencart http:// & www error

Tags: http, opencart, config, no-www

I have changed config file in opencart from http://mywebsite.in/ to http://www.mywebsite.in/ .

Now the problem is when i visit mywebsite.in, the website doesn't work. How can i redirect to www or http.

do i need to do something in library/url.php

public function link($route, $args = '', $secure = false) {
        if ($this->ssl && $secure) {
            $url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '/.\') . '/index.php?route=' . $route;
        } else {
            $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '/.\') . '/index.php?route=' . $route;
        }

```
    if ($args) {
        if (is_array($args)) {
            $url .= '&amp;' . http_build_query($args);
        } else {
            $url .= str_replace('&', '&amp;', '&' . ltrim($args, '&'));
        }
    }
```

Please help me.
Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aditya, You need to make .htaccess file in root folder and then do following changes on that file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.in$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebsite.in/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It will forcefully redirect to www. If it's work then give me whote.

Comment: It still doesn't work, if i go to any inner page, and click on home through navigation  then it redirecting to mywebsite.in only. its oc 2.2 and i dont know whats wrong with these htaccess and config files. please help me.

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.in$

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebsite.in/$1 [R=301,L] 


</IfModule>


# END WordPress

This is my htacess file.

Comment: can we do something to work website on mywebsite.in domain. instead of putting http or www before url?

Comment: @Aditya Do you enable "Use SEO URLs" option in admin → system →
setting → server tab ? This should be enable otherwise your .htaccess file will not work.

Comment: it is already enabled. i will provide you the domain : shreejifoods.in

Comment: @Aditya It's working fine. When I tried to use URL shreejifoods.in so it is redirected to www URL. Tried to other browser or clear cookies.

Comment: http://shreejifoods.in/index.php?route=product/category&path=60_64

visit this. and see its not redirecting to www. and website doesnt work

Comment: Don't change any core file of file php and verify your .htaccess code with
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymLinks 
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shreejifoods.in$
 RewriteRule (.*) http://www.shreejifoods.in/$1 [R=301,L] 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>`

Comment: verify means should i replace the code? with your code?

Comment: Yes @Aditya, You will try my code in .htaccess file and if you did any change on seo_url.php (controller) then make it opencart original code. This code is work fine in my project.

Comment: ok i havnt change anything in any php file. let me try your code. lets see.. i will let you know.

Comment: @Aditya Give me Upwhote my ans if it's really useful.